# PhantomJS Mocha 'Can't find variable: HTMLSpanElement'

Tags: phantomjs, mocha.js

I am trying to run my mocha tests with PhantomJS (through grunt-mocha). The first test throws a `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: HTMLSpanElement`, while the second one tests fine. In Chrome, both of these tests pass. Any ideas on why this might not be working?

This throws `'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: HTMLSpanElement'`:

```
it 'Instance of Span', ->
    $el = $('<span></span>')
    expect($el[0]).to.be.an.instanceof(HTMLSpanElement);
```

This test passes:

```
it 'Instance of Element', ->
    $el = $('<span></span>')
    expect($el[0]).to.be.an.instanceof(HTMLElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS does not implement `HTMLSpanElement`.

```
phantomjs> HTMLSpanElement
Can't find variable: HTMLSpanElement
phantomjs> HTMLAnchorElement
{
   "prototype": {
      "getParameter": "[Function]"
   }
}
```

In reality, PhantomJS *might* be able to implement it, I think the version of webkit it uses depends on the libraries it is compiled against. How to compile it against a different version of webkit than the default and whether it will work or not, I have no idea.